# Code isn't reading the whole string

Tags: c

Problem:

> The first scan is the number of converting numbers the user requests. The following are the ones that are are going to be converted.
>   The point is to count the number of LEDs that are going to be needed to write these numbers, like the following pic [Numbers in LED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46GnF.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
   int i, j, k, leds, a, clean;

//here i scan the number of times the program will be executed

   scanf ("%i", &a);

   int n[a], l[a];
   char c[101] = {0}; //the string where the numbers will be armazened

   for (i=0; i< a; i++)
   {
       scanf ("%i", &n[i]); //here i get the numbers
   }

   for (i=0; i<a; i++)
   {
       sprintf(c, "%d", n[i]);
       leds = 0; //where the numbers of leds needed will be armazened

       while(c[j] != '\0')
            {
                if(c[j] == '0')
                {
                    leds = leds + 6;
                }
                else if(c[j] == '1')
                {
                    leds = leds + 2;
                }
                else if(c[j] == '2')
                {
                    leds = leds + 5;
                }
                else if(c[j] == '3')
                {
                    leds = leds + 5;
                }
                else if(c[j] == '4')
                {
                    leds = leds + 4;
                }
                else if(c[j] == '5')
                {
                    leds = leds + 5;
                }
                else if(c[j] == '6')
                {
                    leds = leds + 6;
                }
                else if(c[j] == '7')
                {
                    leds = leds + 3;
                }
                else if(c[j] == '8')
                {
                    leds = leds + 7;
                }
                else if(c[j] == '9')
                {
                   leds = leds + 6;
                }
            clean = j;
            j++;

            }


        l[i] = leds; //where the number of leds of each will be armazened to be printed afterwards
   }

   for (i = 0; i<a; i++)
   {
       printf("%i\n", l[i]);
   }

}
```

My input:
3
115380
2819311
23456

The output i get:
27 (the only one thats right)
2
0

what i should get:
27
29
25

I just don't know what im doing wrong, but i think its the c[] and the sprintf. But what should I do?

Sorry if the english isnt really right

Comment: In situations such as this, I highly recommend desk-checking your own code. Be the compiler. Go through each line of code, just as the computer would. Write down and keep track of your variables. That will probably reveal the problem to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not initializing `j`

```
   sprintf(c, "%d", n[i]);
   leds = 0; //where the numbers of leds needed will be armazened
```

should be

```
   sprintf(c, "%d", n[i]);
   j = 0;
   leds = 0; //where the numbers of leds needed will be armazened
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>

   int main(){
   int i, j, k, leds, a, clean;

   //here i scan the number of times the program will be executed

   scanf ("%i", &a);

   int n[a], l[a];
   char c[101] = {0}; //the string where the numbers will be armazened
   int numLeds[] = {6, 2, 5, 5, 4, 5, 6, 3, 7, 6};

   for (i=0; i< a; i++)
   {
       scanf ("%i", &n[i]); //here i get the numbers
   }

   for (i=0; i<a; i++)
   {
       sprintf(c, "%d", n[i]);
       leds = 0; //where the numbers of leds needed will be armazened

       int j = 0;

       while(c[j] != '\0')
       {
           // 48 = zero in ASCII code
           if (c[j] < 48 || c[j] > 48 + 9)
               continue; 
           int digit = c[j] - 48;
           leds += numLeds[digit];
           clean = j;
           j++;

       }


        l[i] = leds; //where the number of leds of each will be armazened to be printed afterwards
   }

   for (i = 0; i<a; i++)
   {
       printf("%i\n", l[i]);
   }

}
```